# var_export with multiple variables of the same name

Tags: php

If I have this, simplified:

```
<?php 
$image='henry.jpg'; 
$name='henry'; 
echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/><p>'.$name.'</p>; 
?>

Some other code

<?php 
$image='walter.jpg'; 
$name='walter'; 
echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/><p>'.$name.'</p>; 
?>
```

I want to convert `$image` and `$name` into an associative array. Using `$arr = compact('image', 'name');` and `var_export` only creates an array for walter thusly

`array ( 'image' => 'walter.jpg', 'name' => 'walter', )`.

Desired output should be

`array ( 
'image' => 'henry.jpg', 'name' => 'henry', 
'image' => 'walter.jpg', 'name' => 'walter', 
)`

How do I achieved this? I have tried `foreach` but it only duplicates `walter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve the exact result you want as that would require having an array with multiple identical keys. However you can generate an array of arrays instead by changing your code slightly:

```
$image='henry.jpg'; 
$name='henry'; 
$arr[] = compact('image', 'name');

$image='walter.jpg'; 
$name='walter'; 
$arr[] = compact('image', 'name');

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
     [image] => henry.jpg
     [name] => henry
  )
  [1] => Array (
     [image] => walter.jpg
     [name] => walter
  ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sqk7k)

Comment: All right, I can work with that. Thank you for the knowledge. It's certainly a time-saver.